# I want to get previous 6 months data from amazon database

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I've an amazon account and I want to get data from my amazon account between current date and previous 6 months. When I set date condition on my "DataRequest" method, the date condition does not work. But when I call this method without date condition, it's perfect work. Can anyone help me where is my problem ?

```
class Amazon {
function DataRequest()
{
    $start = date('Y-m-d');
    $end = '-180';  // previous 6 months
    $request = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_RequestReportRequest();
    $request->setMerchant($this->SELLER_ID);
    $request->setStartDate(new DateTime($start, new \DateTimeZone('UTC')));
    $request->setEndDate(new DateTime($end .' days', new \DateTimeZone('UTC')));
    $request->setReportType('_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_');
    $reportRequestId = $this->invokeRequestReport($this->call_service(), $request);
    return $reportRequestId;
}


function call_service(){
   $service = new MarketplaceWebService_Client($this->channelRepository->awsAccessKeyId(), $this->channelRepository->secretKey(),
       $this->CONFIG,$this->APPLICATION_NAME,$this->APPLICATION_VERSION);

    return $service;
} }
```

Comment: Your question may get more attention if you tag what language you're using to retrieve the information.

Comment: I'm using php language.